# Figuring out an effect size with a P value for a t-test, sample means, and sample sizes

Tags: t-test, p-value, effect-size, statistical-power

An author did not report an effect size so I am hoping you might be able to help me calculate it.

I know the Means are:

```
Condition 1: 326
Condition 2: 558
```

Sample size:

```
Cond1: 11
Cond2: 12
```

```
T-test p value: .04
```

Comment: Was this with the assumption of equal variance or was there some approximate adjustment for inequality such as Welch-Satterthwaite?

Comment: I believe equal variance is assumed. At least, they did not report any adjustment.

Comment: Shall we assume two-sided? Note that the p-value is only reported to 1 significant figure. The calculated effect size can't be more accurate than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, recall the form of the statistic

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Unequal_sample_sizes.2C_equal_variance

Then, see here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#t-test_for_mean_difference_between_two_independent_groups

Now you need an estimate of $\sigma$. You have that $p \approx 0.04$, so we can approximate the $t$-value using t-tables (or the relevant function):

```
 qt(1-0.04/2,df=11+12-2)
[1] 2.189427
```

However, the true value might actually correspond to some rather different value of $t$ -- between 2.13 and 2.25 if the p-value was rounded (true $p$ is between 0.035 and 0.045) -- or between 2.19 and 2.33 if a conservative (rounding up) approach was used (i.e. if say the p-value was calculated as 0.0367 and then reported as being no more than 0.04).

Rearranging the t-statistic formula in terms of $Sp$ (equivalently, $S_{X_1X_2}$ at that first link) of 
$$
\frac{\bar {X}_1 - \bar{X}_2}{t\cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}}}   
$$

Taking the $|t|$ value at 2.19 for the purpose of illustration, this implies an $Sp$ of

$$
\frac{|326 - 558|}{2.19 \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{12}}}  \approx 254
$$

From here you should be able to use the formulas at the second link above.

Comment: Hi Glen - the df for a t-test is typically N-1, why do you sum up here the sample sizes of both groups?

Comment: The df in the calculation of the variance for a *one sample* t-test is n-1. With a two sample t-test you have two samples that contribute to the estimation of the common variance, and they each contribute degrees of freedom to that estimator; there's $n_1$ and $n_2$ observations respectively and they each lose $1$ d.f. due to the estimation of their individual group means. The d.f. in the combined variance estimate about those means is $(n_1-1) + (n_2-1)$. You might like to review the two sample (equal-variance) t-test.