# What to do when p-values are close to alpha?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I am performing t-tests on gene expression data-sets. I am computing the p-value for a specific gene.

From the first data-set, I got a p-value of 0.0510 and from the second data-set I got a p-value of 0.0482. Given that my alpha value is 0.05, I am not sure what decision to take.

Please note that the two data-sets come from the same person and that they are taken under the exact same condition.

What to do in this case?

Comment: What are you comparing to justify a t test?  Is there a rationale for combining the data sets as Stephen suggests.  Why do you pick 0.05 for $\alpha$?  When Fisher selected 0.05 he didn't mean that it should be used religiously.

Comment: What is the best way to select our alpha value? What to do in cases like these where the values are really close to the value?

Comment: http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~wardrop/courses/meta2.pdf ?

Comment: The rejection rule is reject if $p\leq \alpha$. Closeness to $\alpha$ doesn't change the rejection rule. If you wanted to do something different near the significance level the decision to play with the rejection would would have to be made before you saw the data, not after it (i.e. you would have to resolve any such issues before you have the p-values or your tests will no longer have the desired properties.)

Comment: but c'mon, having two p-values close to 0.05 is not the same strength of evidence then having 1 p-value close to 0.05. these p-values should be merged.

Comment: Is it possible to present the raw data for two sets? And what is your specific hypothesis as well as objective ?

Comment: What kind of variable is this 'gene expression'? Is it a yes/no answer (expressed or not) or is it a continuous variable  (degree of expression)? In the case of the latter, then what degree of expression did you determine, and is it a degree that your care about? The p-values are eventually just a matter of precision and you can always improve them with more accurate tests (which means, the p-values are not the main issue). In fields like biology, medicine, etc the effects are nearly always there (the $H_0$ is nearly always false) and it is just a matter of effect size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do a lot of gene expression analysis... You have two major issues:

**1. Statistical understanding**

- @Glen and others had pointed out, you can't just change your decision after you did the test. You may want to control for multiple comparisons if you want, but you shouldn't go back and change your methodology now. You can interpret like this: *I have a gene rejected for my t-test, and the other gene failed to reject. However, the p-values for both tests are close to my chosen alpha. There is barely enough evidence to reject my hypothesis.*

**2. Are you sure you want t-test on gene expression data?**

There're many posts here why t-test is bad on gene expression data. Unless you have very strong reasons, t-test isn't what you're looking for. t-test almost never give sufficient power for gene expression analysis. Please double check on your statistical assumptions. How many replicates do you have? Do you chose t-test just because it's the simplest test?

Comment: I use sumlog function from metap R package to combine two p-values using Fisher's method. > sumlog(c(0.0510, 0.0482)):
chisq =  12.01665  with df =  4  p =  0.01722787 . Could you explain me what is wrong with it? There is quite enough evidence to reject the hypothesis.

Comment: @GermanDemidov Are you the OP? I see different user name?

Comment: @GermanDemidov How many replicates do you have? Can you briefly describe your experiment in your question (edit)?

Comment: No, I took 2 p-values from the original post (as u can see) and merged them. I am not an OP, I just wander why 2 tests with p-values <0.05 and slightly >0.05 is "barely enough evidence to reject my hypothesis".

Comment: I would also say that since p-values have a well-defined relation with the effect size for t-test (in case if the sizes of groups are equal), we can see consistent biological effect of particular size here since p-values are quite similar, and it can be estimated from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49259/figuring-out-an-effect-size-with-a-p-value-for-a-t-test-sample-means-and-sampl (I found it useful because, even there is no direct confirmation for equality of sizes of groups, OP says "two data-sets come from the same person and that they are taken under the exact same condition."

Comment: @GermanDemidov I welcome you for an answer. But I still believe t-test isn't normal for gene expression analysis. Combining p-values from two bad tests don't change anything.

Comment: it depends how do you apply t-test. Limma uses t-test and nobody argues its accuracy.

Comment: @GermanDemidov It uses moderated t-test .... Moderated t-test is not the t-test in this question .......

Comment: @German Demidov Your comments are apparently useful and hence hence need to be synthesized in the form of an Answer.

Comment: @subhashc.davar thank you. I am not an expert in statistics and percentage of my right answers (I guess) will be lower than percentage of my wrong answers. That's why I prefer to ask if my reasoning is correct in comments section instead of giving an (most probably wrong) answer.

Comment: @GermanDemidov You're welcome to post your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you can't combine the datasets and run the analysis on both? The additional observations should give you more power and likely bring down your Standard Errors enough to give you the lower p-values you want.

Comment: Would it make sense to use a Bonferroni correction in this case instead of combining the data-sets?

Comment: Or, you could do a basic meta analysis.

Comment: "Is there any reason you can't combine the datasets and run the analysis on both?" --  this is not okay after the fact of looking at the p-values for them separately. Otherwise this would basically be significance hunting (or more rarely, perhaps insignificance hunting)

Comment: @Glen_b This answer is wrong. It makes absolutely no sense to combine two genes in a gene expression analysis.

Comment: @SmallChess I think the OP said s/he has one gene in two different data-sets. Does your point still apply?

Comment: I would say s/he is looking for the same gene and she did pre-selection of the target gene before the analysis of p-values. So it is legit.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a question about p-values, but rather about how statistical reasoning works. This is why it is important, to think about your confidence level (alpha), before you conduct an experiment. P-values do NOT express the strength of the effect that you are measuring (even if that's what they are often misinterpreted to).

**Choice of alpha**

When you choose alpha, what you are choosing is your long run frequency of discovering things that are not actually there. The lower alpha, the less things you will be falsely discovering. This is easily quantifiable, and alpha% of your discoveries will be wrong in the long run. What is harder (or even impossible) to quantify, is what your test loses in terms of power when you choose a lower alpha, this is why it's usually easier to think in terms of "how bad is it if I discover something that's wrong".

**What to do**

The question that you are trying to answer is defined by the test you are using, and since you are giving values around 5%, I'm guessing that's what you went with. To be scientific, you need to reject the one below 5% and not reject the one above 5%, only that way, type 1 errors will be a meaningful measure for your experiments in the long run.

If both experiments correspond to the same null-hypothesis, you can apply a Bonferroni correction (which will result in your overall hypothesis not being rejected, since you are so close to 0.05 in both tests). In fact, if you want to make 1 statement that summarizes both experiments, that is likely what you need to do.

In any case, it might be helpful if you expand on what exactly you are measuring, and how the samples relate to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Norm Matloff open textbook "From Algorithms to Z-Scores" out of the University of California.  In section 17.11.1 he goes over the issues of significance testing and its 'basic fallacy' in easy-to-understand terms.

What he suggests you do is look critically at statistics and how it's used (rather than something applied blindly).  He writes the following:

- Form a confidence interval.
- Pay close attention to the width of the confidence interval.  If it
  is too wide, your analysis may be suggesting that the power of your
  analysis is not sufficient at that you may need more data.

http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjgktOexujWAhUJwYMKHSz6DJkQFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fheather.cs.ucdavis.edu%2F~matloff%2F132%2FPLN%2FProbStatBook.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2uvuxQfHIFqcqceOp4mNpB

Answer (score 0):

You have a population and you want to make some conclusions about the population from a data sample from that population. You have one well defined question to ask, it can be: is one particular gene differentially expressed (have different mean expression level, if you want to analyse difference in means)? What you should ideally do: perform power analysis, determine your effect size of interest and other parameters, find the size of the sample that you need to investigate to achieve the power you need and perform a statistical test. If you have $p > \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is eg 0.05, then bad luck and the safest choice is to say that you were not able to discover an effect here.

This is an ideal case. I guess this is not true for your situation. Probably, you are interested in effect of any size or forgot to perform power analysis or had a limited budget to achieve desired power (in the beginning) and in the end you had more money, or you performed sampling two times independently with another researcher. Then you may summarise the test statistics from two different samples.

The ideal case would be to merge 2 datasets in one and perform a statistical test using this merged dataset, however, it is not always possible for various reasons. It can be a) you do not have an access to the raw data from some of your datasets, b) you are sure that there are some confoudning effects which are fixed within datasets, but different between them, etc. In this case you can use just p-values from two different tests and merge them into 1 p-value. There are a lot of methods to do that, each has its advantages and disadvantages, and these methods were investigated in for example meta-analysis studies. I can make a reference to a [wikipedia article about Fisher's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method). There are [other methods](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2771157/).

What you should keep in mind, merging 2 pvalues:

1) Sampling should be performed independently from the same population. You should ask the same question (in other words - perform the same statistical tests) for different samples.

2) No null hypothesis is actually true in real life. In other words - you will almost always achieve your pre-defined level of significance at some point. So you need to stop to include new datasets in your "meta-analyses" at some point. As an example, @SmallChess mentioned that some statistical models are oversimplified in order to get "useful models" instead of "100% correct models", so, using for example t-test where your data does not actually meet your assumptions may lead to the wrong statements about the probability of 1st type Error. That's why people perform additional experimental validation on computational-based discoveries in life sciences.

3) Having a p-value "on the border" of $\alpha$, which is equal to 0.05 in your case, it is quite dangerous to continue sampling "small" samples - it may cause your p-value fall below $\alpha$ just by chance. There are some developed methods about how you should proceed when you are not satisfied with your p-values.

It is not the full list, so if you are interested, you should read some guidelines on how to perform meta analysis.

Regarding your question: having a question "are the means of (1 particular and fixed) gene expression different for different condition" and getting pvalues you mentioned, assuming that your statistical model is adequate enough for the data, merging these two pvals will give you (R-code):

```
sumlog(c(0.0510, 0.0482)): chisq = 12.01665 with df = 4 
p = 0.01722787
```

You can reject your null hypothesis and report a difference in means here. It is quite difficult to report an effect size here, but I strongly advice you to work on an effect size's estimation since it is a good practice in reporting your statistical results.